# Data changed after MySQL backup in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I've a problem with MySQL. After the export and import process in phpmyadmin, some data are not showing and some of them has been changed(not changed in database, but showing differently!). The collation of the first server's MySQL is latin1_swedish_ci. I've changed new server's database collation multiple times but nothing changed!

An example of data change is images address in database:

[https://i0.wp.com/madomartcom.wpcomstaging.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/industrial-ss-mixing-vessel-500x500-jpeg-500×500-.jpg](https://i0.wp.com/madomartcom.wpcomstaging.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/industrial-ss-mixing-vessel-500x500-jpeg-500%C3%97500-.jpg)

has changed to:

[https://madomart.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/industrial-ss-mixing-vessel-500x500-jpeg-500Ã—500-.jpg](https://madomart.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/industrial-ss-mixing-vessel-500x500-jpeg-500%C3%83%E2%80%94500-.jpg)

× ====changed to=====> Ã—

or some data are not showing:

https://madomart.com/store-list/

you can check the difference:

https://madomartcom.wpcomstaging.com/store-list/

Any idea how can I fix it?
Thanks

I've changed the collation of server database and charset of the tables but nothing happend!

Comment: the database collation/charset settings are just the default for new tables, and the table settings are just the default for new columns.  if you've already loaded the data, you need to change each text/char/varchar column, or start over.

Comment: What do you mean "start over"?

Comment: I mean do over whatever you did to migrate your data, but have the right settings before you load the data